# how to get a daily count of open transactions per day?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, timestamp, sql-timestamp

I have a table called **shoe_service**

[image: simplified table]

Take cancelled to mean a false transaction or a mistake and not to be counted. Take a closed_at of null to mean it hasn't been closed yet.
I have been able to find how many transactions are open on a particular day using:

[image: SQL code i have tried]

This returns the exact data I want:

[image: expected returned data]

However I don't want it just for a particular day that i have to manually input and change.
I would like a table that returns a row for each day and shoe type.

i.e.

[image: an example of what I want to see]

i would expect 1460 (=4*365) rows of data.
Essentially i want to open up my query to extend it for each and every day not just the singular timestamp i have input. The data is recorded via timestamp.

I imagine i would have to do some sort of sequential date join but i am not sure how to go about this?

sorry for not being able to embed the images

Comment: Please do not use pictures for including your code (sql statements) but include but put right into your question.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to put it right into my question straight away. do you have any suggestions regarding my question?

Comment: Add the date column both to the SELECT list and the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You do not need any reputation to use [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query.

`select cast(opened_at as date) as date,shoe_type,count(*) as [open] from shoeTable where state='open' group by cast(opened_at as date),shoe_type order by cast(opened_at as date)`

Comment: thank you, however that gives me a count of just 1 for each because opened_at is a timestamp.
What I need to do is join a date column i.e. 01/01/2018, 02/01/2018 ... 30/12/2018, 31/12/2018. 
and group it by all the transactions done on each day for each product.

the query i provided is the correct answer for that specific date. however i need it for each date in a year.

I provided my required output in the question.

Comment: you just need to cast opened_at as date like this "cast(opened_at as date) " So replace [opened_at] by cast(opened_at as date) in the above query, no need to add extra column

Comment: Thank you, I get what you're trying to explain however I need to know how many are open for "every" date. Using your method i have gaps in the dates. there should be 365 rows for each product showing even when a product has 0 open on a given day.

Is there any way to replace the part of my code where I specify the date to be more general for every day of the year?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-:(first date of the year to current date) but if you want for 365 days then replace getdate() in the query with last date of the year.

```
 WITH mycte AS
    (
      SELECT cast(DATEADD(yy, year(GETDATE()) - 1900, 0)  as datetime) DateValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  DateValue + 1
      FROM    mycte   
      WHERE   DateValue + 1 < getdate()
    )
    SELECT  cast(DateValue as date) as [Date],'boot' as Shoe_type,isnull([open],0) as [Open]
    FROM    mycte a left join (select cast(dt as date) as date,shoe_type,count(*) as [open] from YOURTABLENAME where state='open' and shoe_type='boot' group by cast(dt as date),shoe_type ) b
    on cast(DateValue as date)=b.date 
    union 
    SELECT  cast(DateValue as date) as [Date],'sandal' as Shoe_type,isnull([open],0) as [Open]
    FROM    mycte a left join (select cast(dt as date) as date,shoe_type,count(*) as [open] from YOURTABLENAME where state='open' and shoe_type='sandal' group by cast(dt as date),shoe_type ) b
    on cast(DateValue as date)=b.date 
    union
    SELECT  cast(DateValue as date) as [Date],'trainer' as Shoe_type,isnull([open],0) as [Open]
    FROM    mycte a left join (select cast(dt as date) as date,shoe_type,count(*) as [open] from YOURTABLENAME where state='open' and shoe_type='trainer' group by cast(dt as date),shoe_type ) b
    on cast(DateValue as date)=b.date
    union
    SELECT  cast(DateValue as date) as [Date],'shoe' as Shoe_type,isnull([open],0) as [Open]
    FROM    mycte a left join (select cast(dt as date) as date,shoe_type,count(*) as [open] from YOURTABLENAME where state='open' and shoe_type='shoe' group by cast(dt as date),shoe_type ) b
    on cast(DateValue as date)=b.date 
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction!
for security reasons i'm not actually working with a shoe data set. That is a very simplified version with way more than 4 types (in fact there's 340) which is why I was looking for a more general solution.

Comment: I am happy with my current query. I just need it to show every day of a year instead of just 1 date.